# Having difficulty printing items from different page together

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse the link of different retaurants from it's landing page and then scrape the `name` and `address` of each restaurant after navigating to it's target page. There are few restaurants having green colored `Featured` icon attached to their links such as the image below.

[Link to the landing page](https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants)

What I want to do is scrape that information from the landing page `(whether a restaurant is featured)` but print that very information along with ***`name`*** and ***`address`*** when my browser is at target page.

***How can I print the `name`, `address` and whether a restaurant is `Featured` at the same in my current `print` command?***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def fetch_info(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    itemlinks = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.restaurant-header")))]

    for itemlink in itemlinks:
        driver.get(itemlink)
        name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.name"))).text
        address = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".address-text-rest-menu span"))).text

        print(f'{name}\n{address}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        fetch_info(driver,url)
    finally:  
        driver.quit()
```

Expected results (`Featured` is available in the landing page):

```
Doughboy's Pizza - Cottage Grove
447 W. Cottage Grove Rd Cottage Grove WI, 53527
Not Featured

Silver Mine Subs - Beltline
2601 W Beltline Hwy Madison WI, 53713
Not Featured

Adamah Neighborhood Table
611 Langdon St Madison WI, 53703
Featured
```

One such `Featured` icon attached to some links in landing page.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `(By.XPATH, 'ng-if="::restaurant.featured"')`

Comment: You didn't understand my question @Moshe Slavin. I have already parsed that `Featured`. What I can't do is print that `Featured` together with `name` like I tried above. Thanks.

Comment: only if "featured" or the other text if there is text e.g. sponsored? And what to return if nothing present?

Comment: If nothing present then `No`. Take a look at my script above where I've already defined that. I'm only after that `Featured` from landing page. Thanks.

Comment: So if it says sponsored, for example, you want to return No?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by wrong results?

Comment: Share your current and desired output

Comment: Finally found you in the loop @sir Andersson. I'll update the post for clarity.

Comment: "I will definitely get wrong results" is a useless description of your problem.

Comment: I've edited my post to bring the clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print name along with Featured (if it's found), try

```
def fetch_info(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.restaurant-header")))
    featured = []
    for item in items:
        try:
            item.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::div//span[.="Featured"]')
            featured.append('Featured')
        except:
            featured.append('Not featured')
    itemlinks = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in items]

    for itemlink, is_featured in zip(itemlinks, featured):
        driver.get(itemlink)
        name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.name"))).text

        print(f'{name}\n{is_featured}')
```

Comment: @asmitu I wasn't sure :) Just made an assumption that this is your desired script behavior

Answer (score 0):

Something like as follows? I have parsed the required info into a list you can then loop and navigate to as required. Print at the page if you want etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re

url = 'https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants'
d  = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
featured = ['featured' if re.search('ng-if="::restaurant\.featured"',ad.get_attribute('innerHTML')) is not None else 'No' for ad in WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".rest-list-information")))]
titles = [[title.text, title.get_attribute('href')] for title in d.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rest-list-information a")]
results = list(zip(titles,featured))
for result in results:
#     if result[1] == 'featured':
#         print(result[0][1]) #navigate if required etc
    print(result[0][0], result[1])
    #d.get(result[0][1])  ##do what you want here
```

Comment: Why do you need to navigate to them I guess would be by next question? You can get the same outcome without navigating don't you? Sorry if I am not understanding you.

Comment: Why next question? My only question was this to print them together in the target page. Your script never followed the scraped links from landing page. In fact you didn't parse the links from the first page either?

Comment: You want to know the title and whether featured. Why visit each page to do that? The first page has all that info doesn't it?

Comment: Please feel free to go through the description above. Btw, why I want to print that `Featured` after navigating away from the current page is that there are several information I will parse as well.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense. But then you could simply loop the results above and if Featured navigate to. I would simply extend the code to include the  url to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the div that contains both the restaurant link and the related Featured button, instead of just the restaurant link:

```
<div class="rest-list-information">
  <a href="/madison-wi/restaurants/adamah-neighborhood-table-madison">Adamah Neighborhood Table</a>
  <div class="featured-border featured-border--green featured-border-left" style="">
    <span>Featured</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you can get the  two related items, restaurant name and Featured button.

**Note:** This is not tested. I don't remember very well Selenium/Python syntax, but it should give you a start.

```
restaurants = [driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "rest-list-information")]

for restaurant in restaurants
 restaurant_name = restaurant.get_attribute('href').text
 try:
  featured = name.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='featured-border--green']").text
 except:
  featured = "No"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following way instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def fetch_info(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    all_items = []
    for item in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".rest-list-information > .information"))):
        item_link = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.restaurant-header").get_attribute("href")
        
        try:
            featured =  item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".featured-container[ng-if='::restaurant.featured']").text
        except Exception: featured = "Not Featured"
        
        all_items.append([item_link,featured])
    
    for container in all_items:
        driver.get(container[0])
        name = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.name"))).text
        address = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".address-text-rest-menu span"))).text
        featured = container[1]
        print(name,address,featured)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        fetch_info(driver,url)
    finally:  
        driver.quit()
```